# Я пишу телеграм бота на библиотеке Telebot. Хочу сделать обратную связь в боте

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

При написании бота возникла идея сделать обратную связь для пользователя бота.Но хз как правильно это сделать.Хотелось что бы условный пользователь хотел сделать заказ или написать о проблеме с ботом, и при нажатии кнопки в боте "тех.поддержка" ему вылетало сообщение "напишите вашу проблему а мы вам ответим " он пишет и отправляет сообщение, а оно приходит мне с его именем, ну или в тг группу.Подскажите как можно было бы это сделать